# Предупреждения Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

Xcode постоянно выписывает предупреждения и ошибки. С большей частью предупреждений я нашел способ бороться в настройках, но вот например от этой не удалось избавится. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне удобно работать через s.data(), и самое главное что оно работает, но эти постоянные предупреждения сильно отвлекают. Еще эти резкие красные строки когда я просто не успел дописать код, а программа уже на "пол экрана" выписывает красную ошибку.
В общем, как можно отключить ошибки и предупреждения в целом, или хотя бы конкретно для этого предупреждения на фото?

Comment: В данном случае у вас действительно серьёзный косяк, т.к. вы пытаетесь писать в память, которая для этого не подготовлена. Нельзя просто так взять и записать сырую строку в пустую `std::string`.

Comment: В олимпиадах это используются, потому что удобно и самое главное работает) Дак, а как все-таки убрать предупреждение?

Comment: Вообще `data()`, который возвращает `char*` без `const` есть начиная с C++17. Поэтому тупо для подавления ворнинга в ваших адовых олимпиадах можно попробовать включить соответствующий стандарт языка. Но UB это, конечно, никуда не денет. Ещё можно извратиться и написать `&s[0]` вместо `s.data()`.

Comment: а может для начала немного памяти в строке выделить? scanf не знает о такой строке и не может выделить память (да он и не пытается. а вот ascanf - умеет, но с такой строкой также не работает).

Comment: @KoVadim вообще там же буферок есть для short-string-optimization.

Comment: да, есть. Но его размер не специфицирован. Но вообще то подобное поведение - UB - [ Modifying the past-the-end null terminator stored at data()+size() to any value other than CharT() has undefined behavior.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data)

Answer (score 0):

В настройках проекта, **Target - Build Settings - Warnings(All languages) - Typecheck Calls to printf/scanf**. Поставить "NO".

Comment: ох ох. очень плохой совет. Собственно как и идея в вопросе. Когда то это UB выстрелит очень сильно и хорошо, если результатом будет просто проигранная олимпиада, а не людские жизни.